# VBA-Count the number of times 2 values are in the same column

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

I am iterating through a workbook and I want to check if a value occurs in another worksheet even once and it is not already in column A of scrap2, then append it to column A of scrap2. Otherwise, if it already in column A of scrap2, then go to the next iteration. I want something like a pass statement in Python. The current results I am getting are multiple copies of the same value and not every unique value.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ws As Worksheets 
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 
    ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2

    For I = 1 To ws_num
        ind = 9
        name_ind = 7
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate
        Do While ind <= 39
    If IsError(Application.Match(Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value, Worksheets("scrap2").Range("A7,A30").Value, False)) Then
                 Worksheets("scrap2").Range("A" & name_ind).Value = Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value
            Else
                Worksheets("scrap2").Range("A" & name_ind).Value = Worksheets("scrap2").Range("A" & name_ind).Value


            End If
            ind = ind + 1
            name_ind = name_ind + 1
        Loop


    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Before you paste the value in Column A, search Column A for that value (like you did in the other worksheet). If its' there, don't paste.

Comment: How would you first search column A and then not paste if it's there? I thought that was what I was doing with application.match

Comment: How would I not paste, is there a pass/continue/null in vb?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. By "don't paste" I meant add an `If...Then` statement that detects the Match and only pastes if there's no match.  I'm working on a real answer now

Comment: Doesn't `Worksheets("scrap2").Range("A" & name_ind).Value = Worksheets("scrap2").Range("A" & name_ind).Value` just replace the cell value with itself?

Comment: Yes, it does. I would just say pass or continue if there was something like that in excel.

Comment: If you say nothing, that's the same as "passing". Did you know the "Else" clause is optional?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub Main()

Dim ws As Worksheets 
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 
ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2
Dim SourceCell As Range, DestinationRange As Range


For I = 1 To ws_num
    ind = 9
    name_ind = 7
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate
    Do While ind <= 39
        'Set these to variables for readability
        Set SourceCell = Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind)
        Set DestinationRange = Worksheets("scrap2").Range("A7:A30") ' NOT ("A7,A30")

        If IsError(Application.Match(SourceCell.Value, DestinationRange, False)) Then
             Worksheets("scrap2").Range("A" & name_ind).Value = SourceCell.Value
             name_ind = name_ind + 1 'Put this here so it doesn't leave blank lines
        Else
             'You don't really need this section. You can just omit the "Else" line.
        End If

        ind = ind + 1
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```